# binding.pry せずに、指定された行で pry したい

Tags: ruby, pry

binding.pry をコードに挿入すると、その時点で ruby プロセスの実行が止まり、 pry を起動、デバッグ実行のようなことができます。

利用している library が何かおかしい場合、その中の特定の行で binding.pry したくなることがあります。 このとき、このライブラリがグローバルにインストールされた gem であるような環境である場合においては、ライブラリのソースを編集することなく binding.pry したくなります。

#### 質問

ソースコードを改変せずに、ライブラリコードの特定の行において binding.pry 相当のことはできますでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

byebug が便利だと思います。

[printデバッグにさようなら！Ruby初心者のためのByebugチュートリアル - Qiita](https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/5aaf323ab4f24b526a61)

```
% cat hoge.rb       
require_relative 'fuga'

Fuga.new.fuga

% cat fuga.rb       
class Fuga
  def fuga
    @fuga = 123
    puts "fuga=#{@fuga}"
  end
end

% ruby hoge.rb
fuga=123

% byebug hoge.rb

[1, 3] in /tmp/hoge.rb
=> 1: require_relative 'fuga'
   2: 
   3: Fuga.new.fuga
(byebug) break fuga.rb:4
Created breakpoint 1 at /tmp/fuga.rb:4
(byebug) cont
Stopped by breakpoint 1 at /tmp/fuga.rb:4

[1, 6] in /tmp/fuga.rb
   1: class Fuga
   2:   def fuga
   3:     @fuga = 123
=> 4:     puts "fuga=#{@fuga}"
   5:   end
   6: end
(byebug) @fuga
123
(byebug) @fuga = 456
456
(byebug) cont
fuga=456
```