# bundle exec で実行することになる ruby 実行ファイルのパスを取得したい

Tags: ruby, bundler

[binding.pry せずに、指定された行で pry したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42976/754)

^ こちらの質問で、 third party の gem の debug をしたい場合には、 byebug を利用すると良い、ということを学びました。ここで、 `bundle exec コマンド` で実行することになる ruby の executable を、 byebug の引数に与えて実行したい、と思っています。

なので、この `bundle exec コマンド` で実行することになる ruby 実行ファイルを、プログラム的に取得したいと思いました。

## 質問

`bundle exec コマンド` で実行することになる、そのコマンドの executable のファイルパスを取得したいと思っています。これを実現する方法はありますでしょうか?

Comment: この質問だと、ファイルパスを知りたいのが「`ruby`コマンド」なのか、「gemなどが提供するコマンド(`irb`や`rails`や`rubocop`コマンドなど)」なのか、不明瞭だと思いました。意図を考えると後者かなあと思うのですが、そこを明確にしていただけると回答しやすいかも知れません。

Comment: @MasatakaKuwabara 修正しました

Answer (score 0):

拙作になりますが、こちらでやりたいことを満たせそうでしょうか？
https://rubygems.org/gems/process-path
https://github.com/yagihiro/process-path